# Excel - Read a value in one cell and replace it with a string from in another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a massive spreadsheet of information I need to reconcile.

Sheet one has a list of reference numbers in columns -

```
AA1
AA2
AA3 etc.
```

Sheet two has a list of those references appended to a value in columns -

```
AA1 Triplo lego
AA2 Duplo lego
AA3 Small lego
```

I need a formula that will identify a value in sheet1, (AA1) search for that value in the list in sheet2 (AA1 Triplo lego) and populate the sheet1 cell with that value. (All the values in sheet 2 are unique)

I've looked at match and vloopup so far but can't seem to be able to work out how to do it. All help appropriated. Thank you.

Comment: Please post the VLOOKUP you tried.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find partial match in sheet 2 (AA1 Triplo lego written in one cell), and if your reference numbers are always 3 characters, then you can use below formula in cell `B1`. Drag it to the bottom.

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$600,SUMPRODUCT(ROW(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$600)*(--(A1=LEFT(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$600,3))*1)),1)
```

[image]

Comment: Why use a sumproduct array string comparison?  That makes the formula long, clunky, and slow performing.  Just use Match with a wildcard: `=INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$A,MATCH(A1&"*",Sheet2!$A:$A,0))`